# writing equations in objective c for iOS app

Tags: objective-c, ios, equation

So I want to start out by saying I'm not a programmer by any means. What I want to do is build a productivity app to help me with my everyday job. Here's what I have.

```
    float u = ([startRate.text floatValue]);
    float v = ([grossProfit.text floatValue]);
    float w = y/40;
    float x = (x - z);
    float y = ([commissionRate.text floatValue]);
    float z = x / y;
    myPayRate.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%3.2f", z];
```

So if the user enters...

```
u = 80
v = 800
y = 1.17
```

Then I need z to come out as 51, but instead I get "inf". Any help or insight is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Side note: You should remove the parentheses from the above code. They are all redundant and none of them make the code any clearer.

Answer (score 4):

You are initializing `x` as `x - z`. Where is `x` supposed to come from?

(Perhaps that's supposed to be `w - z` instead, since I don't see anything using `w`?)

Answer (score 1):

What is most likely happening here is that the value of `[commissionRate.text floatValue]` is 0. Perhaps either `commissionRate.text` is empty or the value isn't being converted from a string to a float correctly, probably because the value of the string is different from what you expect it to be.

Put a breakpoint on the line `float z = x / y;` and examine the values of variables?

Answer (score 1):

maybe rearranging your code like so would help.

```
float u = ([startRate.text floatValue]);
float v = ([grossProfit.text floatValue]);
float y = ([commissionRate.text floatValue]);
float w = y/40;
float x = (x - z);
float z = x / y;
myPayRate.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%3.2f", z];
```